# Calculating and displaying running total when summary button is clicked

Tags: c#, arrays, list, logic, cumulative-sum

I am trying to figure out how to display the total amount of: processed employees (I enter a new name and set of data when I click the "clear" button after calculating the previous person's data), the total gross pay, total deductions before taxes, total taxes, and the total net pay when I decide to click the "summary" button.

I think a while loop would be a good option since I do not know how many iterations would be needed as opposed to using a for loop. However, I am not too sure. I am not also sure if I should start the code in the calculate button method, or summary button method.

In addition to this, I want to display the total within a message box upon clicking the "summary" button, so I thought a list would be suitable. However, I am not too sure how to get strings like "Number of processed employees: ,Gross pay: , Total deductions: , Total Taxes: , Total net pay: " to be displayed alongside the results in the list provided (results in list are not accumulated at the moment).

So essentially, I am trying to gather and display the accumulated totals in a message box after clicking the summary button. Any help that would guide me towards solving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //list of all results...
        List<decimal> results = new List<decimal>();    
        //constant variables for the tax rate and minimum wage
        const decimal Tax_Rate = .25m;
        const decimal minimum_wage = 9.25m;


        //method that calculates the gross pay
        private decimal gross_pay( decimal hours, decimal rate)
        {
            decimal gross_pay = 0m;
            if (hours > 60)
            {
                decimal double_over_time = 20;
                decimal over_time = hours - 60;
                gross_pay = rate * 40 + (1.5m * rate) * over_time + (2.0m * rate) * double_over_time;
            }
            else if (hours > 40 && hours <= 60)
            {
                //calculates the over time pay.
                decimal over_time = hours - 40;
                gross_pay = rate * 40 + (1.5m * rate) * over_time;
            }
            else 
            {
                gross_pay = hours * rate;
            }
            return gross_pay;
        }



        //method that calculates the tax deduction
        private decimal Taxes(ref decimal hours, ref decimal rate)

        {
           decimal tax_deduction = (gross_pay( hours,  rate) - Before_tax_deduction(ref hours, ref rate)) * Tax_Rate;

            return tax_deduction;

        }

        decimal Before_tax_deduction(ref decimal hours, ref decimal rate)
        {
            decimal before_tax_deduction = 0m;

            if (txtDeductionTextbox.Text == "D0")
            {
                before_tax_deduction =  0;
            }

           else if (txtDeductionTextbox.Text == "D1")

            {
                before_tax_deduction = 10;
            }


            else if (txtDeductionTextbox.Text == "D2")
            {
                before_tax_deduction = 30;
            }

            else if (txtDeductionTextbox.Text == "D3")

            {
                before_tax_deduction = 60;
            }

            return before_tax_deduction;
        }


        //calculates the net pay
        private decimal net_pay(ref decimal hours, ref decimal rate)

        {
            decimal net_pay = 0m;

            net_pay = gross_pay( hours,  rate) - Before_tax_deduction(ref hours, ref rate) - Taxes(ref hours, ref rate);

            return net_pay;
        }


        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal hours = 0m;
            decimal rate = 0m;


            //try catch block for hours,rate, and name fields...checks to see if format is correct. 
            try
            {             
                 string name = Convert.ToString(txtNameTextbox.Text);

                    if (txtNameTextbox.Text == "")

                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter your name.", "Name is missing.");
                    }

                    if (txtDeductionTextbox.Text == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a deduction code.", "Deduction code is missing.");

                    }

                    //converts the input of hours and rate to decimal, so it can be input into the textboxes.
                    hours = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHoursTextbox.Text);
                    rate = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRateTextbox.Text);

                    if (rate < Convert.ToDecimal(minimum_wage))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hourly rate entered does not meet the minimum wage.", "Minimum Wage is missing");

                    }

                    if (hours < 5 || hours >70)
                    {
                       MessageBox.Show("Hours must be between 5 and 70 hours.", "Entry Error.");
                    }


                    gross_pay( hours,  rate);

                    net_pay(ref hours, ref rate);

                    Before_tax_deduction(ref hours, ref rate);

                //displays the Name of employee
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += ("Name: ");
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += name.ToString();

                    //displays the gross pay
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += ("\r\nGross Pay: ");
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += gross_pay( hours,  rate).ToString("c");

                    //displays the before tax deduction
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += ("\r\nDeductions before taxes: ");
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += Before_tax_deduction(ref hours, ref rate).ToString("c");

                    // displays the 25% tax deduction
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += ("\r\nTax: ");
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += Taxes(ref hours, ref rate).ToString("c");

                    //displays the net pay
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += ("\r\nNet Pay: ");
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += net_pay(ref hours, ref rate).ToString("c");

                    //displays the hours worked
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += ("\r\nHours: ");
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += hours.ToString();

                    //displays the rate of pay
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += ("\r\nRate per hour: ");
                    txtResultsTextbox.Text += rate.ToString();

                    txtNameTextbox.Focus();

                results.Add(gross_pay( hours, rate));
                results.Add(Before_tax_deduction(ref hours, ref rate));
                results.Add(Taxes(ref hours, ref rate));
                results.Add(net_pay(ref hours, ref rate));
                results.Add(hours);
                results.Add(rate);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Hours and rate are missing");

            }

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtNameTextbox.Text = "";
            txtHoursTextbox.Text = "";
            txtRateTextbox.Text = "";
            txtDeductionTextbox.Text = "";
            txtResultsTextbox.Text = "";

            //focuses on the name text box after clearing the fields
            txtNameTextbox.Focus();
        }

        private void btnSummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string summary_results = "";

            //displays the results in a message box, but does not display the total or number or employees processed..
            foreach (decimal i in results)
            {
                summary_results += i.ToString("c") + "\n";        
            }

            MessageBox.Show( summary_results , "Summary totals: ");     


        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, one way to get the total from that `List<decimal>` without explicitly using a loop is with LINQ: `results.Sum()`.  It's not really clear where you're stuck, though.  What have you tried?  Are you asking how to add values together?  How to set a label's text?  Your code is already doing things just like that...

Answer (score 1):

Please see my post I explained how to make a running total in c# with code and screenshot.

> [Display running total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826299/display-running-total/46827062#46827062)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly. What you need to add is a variable that keeps track of the totals for calculated results.

If we have a global variable

```
int totalEmployeesProcessed = 0;
```

then each time the calculate button is clicked you would simply need something like

```
totalEmployeesProcessed +=1;
```

Which would add one to the variable.
Now you should be easily able to use this variable when the summary button is clicked.

```
MessageBox.Show("Total Employees:" + totalEmployeesProcessed, "Summary");
```

If you did want to use a list, I would most likely create an employee class or something similar that can hold the data I need. Then when calculating create an employee and add it to a list of objects some relevant code might include:

```
//create a class
public class Employee
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    decimal GrossPay {get;set;}
    decimal NetPay {get;set;}
    //etc...
}
//Create an instance of employee
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employee tempEmployee = new Employee();
    tempEmployee.Name = txtName.Text;
    tempEmployee.GrossPay = gross_pay;
    tempEmployee.NetPay = net_pay;
    EmployeeList.Add(tempEmployee);

}
//Get totals from List<Employees>
private void btnSummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employee TotalEmployee = new Employee();
    for (int i = 0; i < EmployeeList.Count; i++
    {
        TotalEmployee.GrossPay += EmployeeList[i].GrossPay;
        TotalEmployee.NetPay += EmployeeList[i].NetPay;
    }

}
```